# Color coding parentheses and brackets in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

Excel performs some color coding of parentheses according to their "depth":
[image]

Is such a thing possible in Visual Studio (any version)? I know how to modify the color of parentheses and how to do brace matching, but I'm asking about different (and permanent) colors for parentheses (and braces, etc) according to their depth.

I know this isn't possible with vanilla Visual Studio, but is there an addin out in the wild which does this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Rainbow braces" are implemented by the extension [Viasfora](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/19609469-380e-4fcf-bcde-e31caeb658b2).

Comment: Ah, I searched all over for "parenthesis color coding". I'd never heard of "rainbow braces" before, though it is a fantastic name for them.

Comment: Viasfora is great but makes VS lag